# how to pass binding result object in RedirectView

Tags: spring, jsp, jstl

I am new to spring and I am trying to redirect to the same page if the form has errors. I am successful redirecting that but the problem is the form has a dynamic drop down  and the values are not rendered when I return a model object. or when I do ModelAndView(new RedirectView("lookup")) I am able to render the dropdown values but I am unable to display the error messages.

code:   jsp: lookup.jsp

```
<form:form   name="lookupForm" method="POST"  action="search.html"        enctype="multipart/form-data"  >
<div style= "color:red">
<form:errors path="empId" /></br>
<form:errors path="companyName" />
</div>
<form:label path="companyName">Company</form:label>
<select name= "companyList" path="companyName">
<option value="Select">Select</option>
<c:forEach  var="element" items="${listCompany}"> 
<option value="${element.companyName}">${element.companyName}</option>
</c:forEach>
</select>
<form:label path="empId">Employee ID</form:label>
<form:textarea name="empId" path="empId" rows="5" cols="30"/>
<input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"/>
```

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/lookup", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView lookupFormView(ModelAndView model,BindingResult result) {
List<Employee> listCompany = employeeDAO.getCompany();
Employee newContact = new Employee();           
model.addObject("listCompany", listCompany);
model.addObject("command", newContact);
model.setViewName("lookup");
return model;  
}


@RequestMapping(value = "/search", params = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView lookupEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse  response, @ModelAttribute("command") Employee emp,BindingResult result) throws Exception{
empValidator.validate(emp, result);
String lookupEmpId = null;
if (result.hasErrors()) {
return  new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("lookup"));
//return  new ModelAndView("lookup");
}
else{
        -----
```

if i use this return  new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("lookup")); its redirecting to lookup.jsp ,rendering the drop down valus but the error messages are not getting displayed.
if i use this return  new ModelAndView("lookup"); its redirecting to lookup.jsp ,errors are displayed but the dynamic dropdown values are not rendered.

Please help me in finding which part of my code is wrong or Is their a way to display error messages and render dynamic dropdown values

Answer (score 0):

Just return the view name and set the error message in the Model itself. Simply check the error message in the JSP if found then show it.

sample code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", params = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String lookupEmployee(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, 
                    @ModelAttribute("command") Employee emp,BindingResult result) throws Exception{
    empValidator.validate(emp, result);
    String lookupEmpId = null;
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
       emp.setErrorMessage("Your error message.");
       return  "lookup";
    }else{
       ...
       return "successPage";
    }
 }
```